# How to install boost on Mac

Tags: c++, xcode, multithreading, macos, boost

Recently, I am learning multithreading in C++. And I use xcode to write c++.But how to install boost in latest version Xcode 7.0. I tried many ways but all of them failed. Besides,Why people prefer using thread library in boost, instead of thread library included in STL.

Comment: Why do you think that people prefer boost threads to the threads in standard library? ps. there are no threads in the STL, you're probably thinking of the standard library.

Comment: Before [C++ 11 thread](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread), I've opted for [boost threads over pthread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2170222/pthread-vs-boostthread) because I though it was simpler. Since [C++ 11](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/thread/thread/), I've always used the thread from the standard library. BTW, which error did you get when you tried to install boost? how did you tried to install?

Comment: install brew  and then  run command  line --brew install boost. I failed in the first  step. The way to install brew is like this:  ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)".  Failed during: /usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/xcode-select --install

Comment: [How to Install boost via Homebrew?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7298289/how-to-install-boost-via-homebrew)